# htaccess rewrite to support multilingual site with dropdown selector. How to fix this?

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my structure:

in my page example.com I have multiple languages. In the index page, I have also a dropdown menu that you can change your language. This dropdown appears in other pages too.

This is my htaccess for the root file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(en|pl|cz|hu)?$ index.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
```

so, i wrote a code that if the domain is `example.com/en` it will load the English translations.

My problem is on the other pages I can not change the languages and stay on the same page.

So when i am on `www.example.com/en` and click on `link.php` (`example.com/link.php`) I can keep the preffered language this through `Session`

But when I am on `example.com/link.php` and change the language, the result is not correct (the result is an output of some PHP code that need fixed and i believe it does not suit here)

What I thought is to include the `/en/` (or any other language in the urls, like `www.example.com/en/link.php`

But this gives me a 404 error. I believe is because of the htaccess file and that I do not have any folder named `en` etc.

How can I solve this?
Is it a htaccess thing?

What I can think as a logic but not know how to implement is like

when the domain contains `(en|pl|cz|hu)` followed by `/***` do it through the `****.php?lang=$1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: 
**Now htaccess will work only for .php files. **

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(en|pl|cz|hu)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).php$ $2.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]`

Now your link must be
`www.domain.com/en/index
www.domain.com/en/link
www.domain.com/pl/link`

If you have questions, please ask.

Comment: Hmm of course.... i use .*. 
The correct way is `RewriteRule ^(en|pl|cz|hu)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).php$ $2.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]` Sorry about my mistakes.

Comment: You must use domain path for css!
www.domain.com/css_folder/style.css

@Xalloumokkelos, I'm already tested with CSS. All is okey, just use full domain path to .CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(en|pl|cz|hu)/(.*)?$ $2.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
```

and you can store you lang variable in session, like following :

```
// link.php
if (isset($_GET['lang']) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
```

Comment: Thank you but it breaks my css

Comment: Thank you. Please tell me, what if I want to keep www.example.com/link and link to the `en` only?

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos, I don't get it !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `.htaccess` at all for this. You can just have the form `$_POST` back to the page its on.

```
if ($_POST['language']) {
    $_SESSION[KEY]['Language'] = $_POST['language'];
}
```

Then depending on the variable within the session, defines what language to use.

Comment: Use `$_GET['lang']` instead

Comment: @xalloumokkelos it's a dropdown, how is it not a form input?

Comment: @Hazonko, it will be better if the form is sent with `GET` to keep the parameter within the url

Comment: @JCSama well, it's dependant on the website, normally for my clients and the digital marketing team, we make every effort to not display $_GETs. but yes, it'll work just as well either way.